# X server gets killed as soon as python command executes

Tags: python, linux, x11, xserver

I'm a Linux newbie and the concepts of X etc are daunting to me, so please be patient. I'm trying to start X server using the bash command startx in python like

```
cmd = 'startx &' 
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

The problem is as soon as it executes X server gets killed (because the process ends?), but it seems to be working fine when executing on command-line manually (albeit it doesn't return control to that terminal without ctrl + z/c). I also tried something like

```
cmd = 'nohup startx &>/dev/null &'
```

(from what I read subprocess.Popen() should be non-blocking but that does not seem to be the case? Am I misinterpreting the docs?)

but it just blocks execution. How can I get X to get running without blocking execution or quitting? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: does it make sense to have X running before and after your program or only during its run?

Comment: I require it only during my run. This is a Ubuntu VM where I test some automation using "xdotool" which requires a Window Manager to perform actions like finding windows and clicking stuff

Comment: What does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` tell you about why X shut down again? Do you get any output on stdout and stderr?

Comment: It just says  "Shutting down X" as if I issued a "Ctrl+C" to it, so it feels like the subprocess.Popen function is closing the connection or something, but I thought this function is non-blocking and continues execution in parallel with rest of the program

Edit: I also tried this with ```os.system()``` - I get the same issues as described above

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to directly call `X` or `xinit`, rather than `startx`

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ("X",)
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

You may also benefit from making this a context manager to nicely clean up .. all together

```py
import contextlib
import subprocess

@contextlib.contextmanager
def subprocess_X():
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ("X",)
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    try:
        yield p
    finally:
        p.terminate()

...
    # later in your program
    with subprocess_X() as p:
        # work here and may refer to X proc if needed (such as for PID)
```